# Working with plain objects client side?

Tags: typescript

I receive a plain object from the server that i assert as an interface, lets say:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    // ...
}

const person = json as Person;
```

I want to avoid the boilerplate and duplication of wrapping the response in my own class like this:

```
class MyPerson {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    // ...

    public get fullName(): string {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }

    constructor(data: Person) {
        this.firstName = data.firstName;
        this.lastName = data.lastName;
        // ...
    }

    public serialize(): Person {
        return {
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```

But i still want to have methods/getters like `fullName`.

I have considered to use "C-style" classes, passing the plain object around and use functions that take the instance as first argument:

```
function Person_getName(person: Person): string {
    return `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator introduced in TypeScript 2.1 (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html).

So in your example:

```
const MY_PERSON = new MyPerson();
// ...
const person = { ...MY_PERSON, ...json };
```

If you want to understand the syntax a little better there is a good [explanation on Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/object-rest-spread)